# Measure on $(\mathbb R,\mathbb B(\mathbb R))$

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $\mu$ be a measure on ($\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})$) with $\mu(\{x\})=0$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$. And so on be $D \in \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})$ with $\delta := \mu(D) \in (0,\infty)$.
>   How can one show, that to every $ 0 < \alpha < \delta $ a interval $I_\alpha \in \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})$
>   exists with $\mu(I_\alpha \cap D)=\alpha$?

$0 < \alpha < \delta$ because of the precondition and
$0 < \mu(I_\alpha \cap D) < \mu(D)$ concerning the monotony of the measure with $I_\alpha \cap D \subseteq D$ (and $\delta:= \mu(D))$.
In particular it must hold $I_\alpha \cap D \subset D$.
Then $I_\alpha \cap D \in \mathbb{R}$ (uncountable), because $\mu(\{x\})=\mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{x_n\})=0$ can't be greater than $0$.

How can someone conclude, that $\mu(I_\alpha \cap D)=\alpha$?
What's the exact formulation/meaning of $I_\alpha$?

regards

Comment: I assume "And so on be $D\in B(R)$  mit $\delta:=\mu(D)\in(0,\infty) $ is a translation.  What's the original?

Comment: oh sorry, i have changed the 'mit'. Conceptual formulation from german to english..

Answer (score 2):

$\mu (-\infty,x)\cap D]$ is a continuous function. This is because it is increasing and you can check that the jump at $x$ (the difference between the right-hand limit and the left-hand limit) is $\mu (\{x\}\cap D)=0$. By IVP it assumes all values between its infimum , which is $0$, and its supremum, which is $\mu(D)$.

Comment: IVP = intermediate value property

Comment: Thanks, i will view this in-depth, when i have the time for it. I assume that IVP is the same like Intermediate value theorem